# is mixing one time with one way binding in Angualrjs possible inside ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, one-time-binding

I'm using latest **AngluarJS** release,
I was wondering if I can **combine** one time with one way binding in one expression inside **ng-if** directive , some like that:

```
ng-if="(vm.isUnix) && (::vm.isGnsEnabled)"
```

The line above throws an error, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The one time binding token must come first and will mean that once the expression is stable it will no longer be watched.

```
ng-if="::vm.isUnix && vm.isGnsEnabled"
```

If `vm.isUnix` can change during the lifetime of your component and you need to reflect this change in the view, there is no way to prevent a watcher for this expression.

Edit: basically one-time binding is for the entire expression, not for individual properties inside the expression.